# Mic not detected by Web-Browser when webcam is disconnected

Tags: ubuntu, audio, linux-mint, webcam, microphone

All web browsers(tried chrome, firefox, chromium etc) installed on my mint system desktop cannot find the microphone when the webcam is disconnected. But they indeed work fine when I connect webcam(USB connection) along with the mic. This is a fresh mint OS installation on my desktop.

```
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
Release:    19.3
Codename:   tricia
```

Answer (score 0):

This is solved [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1796845#p1796845). Posting the link if it would be helpful for the people who face the same issue